# Image dissapears

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to adopt some code from a tutorial to show an image grid with text from here: https://bryanlrobinson.com/blog/how-to-use-css-grid-to-mix-and-match-design-patterns/

What drives me nuts is that with "my" implementation the images are not shown in Safari when the browser is in full screen, but will be shown when the browser is minimized. In Firefox the images are always shown correctly. The preview from the tutorial in Codepen works correct in Safari. What may be the reason?

I've created a fiddle in jsfiddle to reproduce my issue:
https://jsfiddle.net/t0uo3pb6/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Scenario Selector</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body translate="no">

<section class="promos">

    <div class="promo">
        <h3 class="promo__headline">This is a headline for a promo space</h3>

        <p class="promo__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ac arcu mollis, semper est ac, tincidunt purus. Cras efficitur maximus augue vitae volutpat. Nullam consectetur diam a dictum facilisis. </p>

        <a href="#" class="promo__button">Learn More &raquo;</a>
        <img class="promo__image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1521379770009-7bafd3ec7a23?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=ce4848266618366ad30d7d35764c0bf4" alt="Ocean Scape">

    </div>

    <div class="promo even">
        <h3 class="promo__headline">This is a headline for a promo space</h3>

        <p class="promo__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ac arcu mollis, semper est ac, tincidunt purus. Cras efficitur maximus augue vitae volutpat. Nullam consectetur diam a dictum facilisis. </p>

        <a href="#" class="promo__button">Learn More &raquo;</a>

        <img class="promo__image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1521379770009-7bafd3ec7a23?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=ce4848266618366ad30d7d35764c0bf4" alt="Ocean Scape">

    </div>

</section>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the original fiddle from the article in Codepen which works correctly:
https://codepen.io/brob/pen/dKWdVB?editors=1000

```
<section class="promos">

    <div class="promo">
        <h3 class="promo__headline">This is a headline for a promo space</h3>

        <p class="promo__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ac arcu mollis, semper est ac, tincidunt purus. Cras efficitur maximus augue vitae volutpat. Nullam consectetur diam a dictum facilisis. </p>

        <a href="#" class="promo__button">Learn More &raquo;</a>
        <img class="promo__image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1521379770009-7bafd3ec7a23?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=ce4848266618366ad30d7d35764c0bf4" alt="Ocean Scape">

    </div>

    <div class="promo even">
        <h3 class="promo__headline">This is a headline for a promo space</h3>

        <p class="promo__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ac arcu mollis, semper est ac, tincidunt purus. Cras efficitur maximus augue vitae volutpat. Nullam consectetur diam a dictum facilisis. </p>

        <a href="#" class="promo__button">Learn More &raquo;</a>
        
        <img class="promo__image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1521379770009-7bafd3ec7a23?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=ce4848266618366ad30d7d35764c0bf4" alt="Ocean Scape">

    </div>

</section>
```

Edit: Adding `transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);` to the .promo style indeed solves the issue. I added that to the promo__image style at first, but it must be added to the outer container. Puzzling though: Why does that show up correctly in Codepen but  not in jsfiddle or my static HTML example? Well, I'll never find out. Problem solved - thanks!

Comment: It doesn't solve it - but indeed it's got to do with mix-blend-mode. The image is shown correctly in full scale when this is removed. However, I'd like it to remain.